# Gtk HeaderBar doesn't expand children

Tags: python, linux, gtk, expand, gtkentry

I'm using Gtk to build an application on Linux using Python 3. I'm trying to use a Gtk.HeaderBar. So far it's been working Ok, but it seems that I can't get it to expand it's child widgets. For example:

[image: Gtk.HeaderBar issue]

As you can see above, I've tried putting my Gtk.Entry into the Gtk.HeaderBar, but even with things like Gtk.Entry.set_hexpand(True) it simply refuses to expand. I've even tried putting it inside a Gtk.Box, expanding the Gtk.Box, then adding the Gtk.Entry inside that. Even when I set the Gtk.Entry as a custom title for the Gtk.HeaderBar, this happens:

[image]

What's causing this? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Enabling `hexpand` only says that you want the widget to be *allocated* all the remaining space; it does not actually resize your widget. You want the `halign` property set to `GTK_ALIGN_FILL` (or whatever it's called in Python) *in addition to* hexpand.

Check the diagrams on [this page](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.10/ch28s02.html) for a visual explanation.

Comment: I'd love to say it worked, but it didn't. It's simply refusing to expand either horizontally or vertically, even when using both .set_halign() and .set_hexpand(). It's strange, it works elsewhere in my program. Only the Gtk.HeaderBar doesn't like it. The only thing that seems to work is .set_size_request(), but that doesn't do what I want it to.

Comment: Well guess what? I'm hitting this bug too now! Yay!!!~~ The joys of knowing what you're talking about (but to be fair, this symptom and this fix usually go together...).

Comment: Four years later, same problem. No idea how to make widgets expand in the header bar.

Comment: It appears GTK+ 3.22 has the solution now: [set `hexpand` to `TRUE` for the custom title widget](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/commit/0015ebc4a8f269f6888fcacef3e83e3167241d67) (via Christian Hergert)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Box instead of Headerbar with window.set_titlebar method